# ZeroMQ C++ multi-threaded server example runtime error

Tags: c++, zeromq

I'm trying to run the ZeroMQ [multithreaded C++ server example](http://www.zeromq.org/blog%3amultithreaded-server), which builds fine with

```
$ g++ server.cpp -lpthread -lzmq -o server -Wall
```

Using OS X 10.6.5, gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664), and zeromq2's lastest master branch (Dec 1st). However I'm getting a runtime error immediately after I start the server (with ./server)

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
what(): Operation not supported by device
```

Is the code provided on the blog no longer current? Or or have I misconfigured? ZMQ seems to be working fine for me otherwise on this machine (simple request/reply socket patterns).

Answer (score 2):

Ridiculous. `"tcp://localhost:5555"` will fail, but `"tcp://127.0.0.1:5555"` works fine.

Update 1:

`/etc/hosts` has an entry for `localhost` so I don't believe that's the problem. I've also tried using `tcp://lo:5555` to no success.

Comment: What does your host file look like?  On some recent linux distros I have seen the host file not have an entry for localhost, they instead have an entry for localhost-localdomain. Therefore localhost doesn't resolve.

Comment: It's a ZeroMQ bug - I just hit the same thing and traced through ZeroMQ. It's trying to resolve the hostname as a network interface name and failing. I made a quick change to the library and it appears to work and will post to the ZeroMQ people.